# Fadein images with jQuery before DOM is ready

Tags: jquery, image, fadein, onload

I'm trying to make all images of my website to show up with a fade-in effect, something like www.blu-ray.com, but no luck yet.

Unfortunately in the way I do that and since the body of my webpage is a little huge, images start to show up and render before *$(document).ready* and so when DOM gets ready, the script I'm using will cause already loaded images to hide and re-appear again! Is there anyway to prevent images from showing up and make their visibility to change into "hidden" just at the moment page starts loading?

And **no CSS please**!
Here is the script i'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('img').css("opacity", 0).css("visibility", "hidden");
    jQuery('img').each(function(i) {
        if (this.complete) {
            jQuery(this).css("opacity", 1).css("visibility", "visible");
        } else 
            jQuery(this).load(function() {
                jQuery(this).css("opacity", 0).css("visibility", "visible").animate({opacity: '1'}, 'slow');
            });
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, set the images to hidden in CSS, otherwise live with it.

Comment: but how blu-ray.com did that? they have no hidden attributes in css for img tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CSS to set visibilty

CSS

```
img{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('img').load(function() {
       jQuery(this).css({"opacity": 0, "visibility": "visible"}).animate({opacity: '1'}, 'slow');            
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I said no CSS. Let's assume the user is on a client with no javascript support or disabled javascript, no images will show up. what about that? I just want it the same way as blu-ray.com!

Comment: Got it! I just wanted to be sure if javascript was enabled on client as well! Just needed to add this to the head of my document!

`<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<style type='text/css'>img {visibility:hidden;}</style>");</script>`

Thank you everyone.